# My portfolio issue: element upon mouse hover shifts everything to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css, portfolio

I am trying to create a effect when you hover over my abbrivated name  it expands to its full size however,I've run into a problem that detracts from the visual appeal of the website I'm trying to achieve and makes it appear tacky.What I want is for the element to expand in a isolated manner and does not affect anything else on the website.

Here is the link:https://jsfiddle.net/dkpsgo73/

```
    <nav>
      <header>
        <h1 class="Name">
          [
          <span id="zk-trigger"><span class="Fname"> S</span><span id="hide1" class="hide"><span    class="Fname">eid</span></span>
            J<span id="hide2" class="hide">ama</span>
          </span>
          ]
        </h1>
      </header>
      <!-- Navigational Bar -->
      <div class="nav-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Skills">Skills</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- Navigational Bar -->
    </nav>
```

I read a lot of different advise on the subject, including position absolute and z-index, but I was unable to find a solution because I am still very new to learning how to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
header {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  background-color: #333333ff;
}

/* Font Config */
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  color: #f6f2f0;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
nav {
  /*Keeps the nav fixed*/
  position: fixed;
  /*Size of the nav bar*/
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  /*Spaces out the nav elements*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  /*Blur property*/
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  background-color: #262626ff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #6527a7ff;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
.Name {
  display: inline;
  font-style: italic;
}

#hide1,
#hide2 {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: max-width 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

#zk-trigger:hover #hide1,
#zk-trigger:hover #hide2 {
  max-width: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: max-width 0.5s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.Fname {
  color: #ffc000;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* My Nav List Position */
.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* My Nav List Position */

/* Navigation Link Interaction */
.nav-menu li a {
  color: #f6f2f0;
}

.nav-menu li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover {
  color: #ffc000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Navigation Link Interaction */

/* Added */
header {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <header>
      <h1 class="Name">
        [
        <span id="zk-trigger"><span class="Fname"> S</span><span id="hide1" class="hide"><span class="Fname">eid</span></span>
        J<span id="hide2" class="hide">ama</span>
        </span>
        ]
      </h1>
    </header>
    <!-- Navigational Bar -->
    <div class="nav-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Navigational Bar -->
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your nav goes wider than 100% since it adds the 10px inline-padding. You can avoid this by using `box-sizing:border-box` so that the box size is *inclusive* of padding. Doing so then allows you to justify your navigation bar as `space-between` and thus stopping your nav shifting when your header expands.

EG:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  background-color: #333333ff;
}
/* consistent box-sizing where width is inclusive of padding */
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Font Config */

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  color: #f6f2f0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}


/* Font Config */


/* Navigation Bar */

nav {
  /*Keeps the nav fixed*/
  position: fixed;
  /*Size of the nav bar*/
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  /*Spaces out the nav elements*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  /*Blur property*/
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  background-color: #262626ff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #6527a7ff;
}


/* Navigation Bar */

.Name {
  display: inline;
  font-style: italic;
}

#hide1,
#hide2 {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: max-width 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

#zk-trigger:hover #hide1,
#zk-trigger:hover #hide2 {
  max-width: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: max-width 0.5s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.Fname {
  color: #ffc000;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* My Nav List Position */

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}


/* My Nav List Position */


/* Navigation Link Interaction */

.nav-menu li a {
  color: #f6f2f0;
}

.nav-menu li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover {
  color: #ffc000;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Navigation Link Interaction */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <header>
      <h1 class="Name">
        [
        <span id="zk-trigger"><span class="Fname"> S</span><span id="hide1" class="hide"><span class="Fname">eid</span></span>
        J<span id="hide2" class="hide">ama</span>
        </span>
        ]
      </h1>
    </header>
    <!-- Navigational Bar -->
    <div class="nav-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Navigational Bar -->
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```